# Typesafe Config in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, typesafe-config

I've defined a default configuration in my Spark application which is tucked in `src/main/resources/reference.conf`. I use `ConfigFactory.load()` to obtain the configuration.

When I run the application with `spark-submit` it picks up these defaults. However, when I only want to override a few of the configurations available in `reference.conf` and provide `application.conf`, it does not seem to pick up these overrides. From the documentation I thought that `application.conf` is merged with `reference.conf` when calling `load()`, so that it's not necessary to re-define everything in `application.conf`.

My `reference.conf` looks like this:

```
hdfs {
  rootDir: "/foo"
  dataDir: "hdfs://"${hdfs.rootDir}"/bar"
}

db {
  driver: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  ...
}

...
```

What I'd now like to do is have an `application.conf` with, say, only a custom `hdfs` section because the rest is the same.

I run my Spark app by supplying `application.conf` in both the `--files` parameter, in `--driver-class-path`, and `--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath`. This may be overkill but it works when I create a copy of `reference.conf` and change a few of the fields.

What am I missing?

Comment: What path are you setting for the executor class path?

Comment: Isn't that the one I have listed with `conf`? That one is colon-separated. `files` is comma-separated.

Comment: One thing you have to be aware of is that the path for `--driver-class-path` isn't the same for `spark.exector.extraClassPath`, meaning if you set for example `--driver-class-path "/opt/bla/application.conf"`, the equivalent for the executor need only be `--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=application.conf"`, since `--file` will dump it in the working directory where the executor launches the uber JAR.

Comment: So I can leave off the `files` parameter. Got it. Would this be OK then: `spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/foo/bar.jar:/foo/bar/application.conf`?

Comment: No, you *need* the `--files` parameter in order to send `application.conf` to the worker nodes. The path needs to be: `spark.executor.extraClassPath=bar.jar:application.conf`

Comment: Understood. I'll change it and try again.